# Trigger para verificar existência de dado em outra tabela

Tags: mysql, trigger, syntax-error

Estou tentando criar uma Trigger, utilizando as seguintes tabelas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A trigger ficará na Tabela Transportadora, e precisa somente verificar se em Cidade.codcidade, existe algum valor igual ao Transportadora.Cidade_codcidade, que estou inserindo.

Cheguei no seguinte código, porém está dando erro de syntax:

```
CREATE TRIGGER VerificaCidade BEFORE INSERT ON Transportadora
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.Cidade_codcidade NOT IN (SELECT codcidade FROM Cidade) THEN
    INSERT INTO Cidade (codcidade,
                        cidade,
                        uf)
    VALUES (NEW.Cidade_codcidade,
            'CADASTRAR',
            'CADASTRAR');
   END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Conforme indicação:

> A trigger ficará na Tabela Transportadora, e precisa somente verificar
> se em Cidade.codcidade, existe algum valor igual ao
> Transportadora.Cidade_codcidade, que estou inserindo.

Basta verificar com a função `count` se a quantidade de registros em `cidade` é igual a zero, caso seja verdade, executará o `insert` conforme seu comando original.

```
CREATE TRIGGER VerificaCidade BEFORE INSERT ON Transportadora
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF ((SELECT count(codcidade) FROM Cidade where codcidade = NEW.Cidade_codcidade) = 0) THEN
    INSERT INTO Cidade (codcidade,
                        cidade,
                        uf)
    VALUES (NEW.Cidade_codcidade,
            'CADASTRAR',
            'CADASTRAR');
   END IF;
END;
```